# Returning values from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have in the database:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspConsumeEnrollments]
    (--@File NVARCHAR(300),
     @XML XML,
     @FamilySent INT = 0 OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @FamilySent = 755;
```

Here I am trying to download data:

```
public int Create(FamilyModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var XML = model.GetEnrolmentFromModel().Serialize();
        var RV = -99;
        var familySent = 0;

        using (var imisContext = new ImisDB())
        {
            var returnParameter = new SqlParameter("@RV", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            var xmlParameter = new SqlParameter("@XML", XML);
            xmlParameter.DbType = DbType.Xml;

            var familySentParameter = new SqlParameter("@FamilySent", SqlDbType.Int);
            familySentParameter.Value = 0;
            familySentParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            var sql = "exec @RV = uspConsumeEnrollments @XML, @FamilySent";

            SqlParameter[] myParams = { returnParameter, xmlParameter, familySentParameter };

            var result = imisContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, myParams);

            RV = (int)returnParameter.Value;
            Debug.WriteLine("RV: " + RV);

            try
            {
                familySent = (int)familySentParameter.Value;
            }
            catch { }
            Debug.WriteLine("familySent: " + familySent);
        }

        return RV;
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
    }
}
```

The reference to the procedure works because I get the RV

I have a problem with `FamilySent`: I do not get any value.

In the above example I have `@FamilySent = 755;`

This should be returned and displayed in

```
Debug.WriteLine("familySent:" + familySent);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Does it throw an excpetion? Have you tried to debug it? Also, you should use a reader to get datas from your stored procedure

Comment: @taktak FamilySent obtains NULL. You can say something more about the Reader?

Comment: The reader make you loop over the result of your stored procedure. So you can get every result you need. I'll try to give you an answer that you can test

Comment: @taktak Ok, I'm waiting

Comment: try out my solution, don't forget to complete my code, I only gave you the way to capture datas

Comment: By the way, your @RV isn't really useful. In fact, you should return FamilySent instead of RV (you select **@FamiliySent**, so you don't need **@RV**)

Comment: It's a **stored** procedure - as in a procedure **stored** inside your SQL Server .....

Comment: @Devnet when you ask a question and someone post a solution, please make some return and tell us what worked and what didn't. Stackoverflow is a community and we need your returns.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out :

Modified version of your stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspConsumeEnrollments](
--@File NVARCHAR(300),
@XML XML,
@FamilySent INT = 0 OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT @FamilySent = 755 as FamilySent;
```

C# code :

```
public int Create(FamilyModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var XML = model.GetEnrolmentFromModel().Serialize();
        var RV = -99;
        var familySent = 0;
        using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(connexionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[uspConsumeEnrollments]", cnx))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var xmlParameter = new SqlParameter("@XML", XML);
            xmlParameter.DbType = DbType.Xml;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(xmlParameter);

            var familySentParameter = new SqlParameter("@FamilySent", SqlDbType.Int);
            familySentParameter.Value = 0;
            familySentParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(familySentParameter);

            cnx.Open();

            List<string[]> res = new List<string[]>();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            res.Add(new string[2]{reader.GetName(i),reader[i].ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            // then here get all of your data you need
            if(res.Count > 0){
                foreach(string[] s in res){
                    RV = s[1];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cnx.Close();
        return RV;
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my code, I removed the parameter **@RV** because it is completly useless. I also corrected your stored procedure as you can give a name to your returned FamilySent